# Should i change .config folder ownership that is in my own home directory? Why is it under root?

Tags: permissions, root

This is the screenshot of my own `/home/user` directory, that is `~`. There are two directories with `root` ownership, `.config` and `.local`. All the rest files and directories belongs to my user and my user's group.

[image]

I don't mind, but it makes git always throw a warning `Permission denied`:

```
user@os /var/www/app $ git status
warning: unable to access '/home/user/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/home/user/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
```

I have two questions.

1) Should I change the ownership of these directories for my user?

```
$ sudo chown user:user .local .config
```

2) Why are there any `root` directories in my user's home directory? Shouldn't they all belong to my user? Are they some special directories that has to belong to `root`?

Answer (score 2):

**to answer 1)**
yes, these directories should be owned by you, not root. you can safely `chown` them back to you.

**as for the second question:**
this may happen if you run programs using `sudo`.

You can see why, when you run `sudo env`, which tells you `HOME` is still `/home/username` instead of `/root`.

To avoid such mess you can use `sudo` like this:

```
sudo -u root -H env
```

now you can see `HOME=/root`. Instead of `env` you can use any other command as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb:

*Use **gksudo** or **sudo -H** with programs with a graphical user interface, GUI*.

It is usually GUI programs that create and use configuration files in the home directory. **root** might overwrite the configuration files and grab the ownership, which makes it difficult or impossible to use the the program without sudo.

You can use ***sudo*** without any option to run command line programs with a simple text interface.

Examples:

```
sudo -H nautilus    # look at files with a GUI interface
sudo ls             # list files with a text interface
sudo ls -l          # long list (with permissons etc)
```

Notice that you should ***only use sudo when necessary***. Run most commands with your login name. This decreases the risk to damage the operating system.

The difference between 'sudo -H' and 'sudo' is illustrated here:

```
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ sudo env|grep ^HOME
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
HOME=/home/sudodus

sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ sudo -H env|grep ^HOME
HOME=/root
```